# Scalable Feature Area with Fixed Position Images

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm wanting to create a CSS feature banner that I can display at the top of a web page. The banner would consist of a scalable gradient as a background so it always stays at 100% of the parent div and have an image at each end (left and right) of the div that remain fixed to the edge of the banner. I would also like a dedicated space in the centre of the banner for text.

I'm sure that this is fairly straight forward, but I couldn't find any tutorials specifically on positioning images within other divs that are scalable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of experimentation, I've managed to put together the following solution:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94jf2/)

However, I'm almost certain that there will be unnecessary code in there. Can anyone have a look at this and let me know if there's a way of simplifying the code so it's a little tidier.

Also, you will notice that the middle div has inherited some padding that has resulted in it expanding beyond the height of the left and right divs. If anyone has a solution to this, can you let me know?

Thanks again,

Ross

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#container {
   width: 100%;
}

#container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

#left {
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
}

#middle {
width: 80%;
min-width: 400px;
max-width: 1000px;
height: auto;
color:white;
text-align:center;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;

/* fallback */
background-color: #1a82f7;

/* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));

/* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

/* Firefox 3.6+ */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

/* IE 10 */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

/* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
}

#right {
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Responsive Banner Test</h1>
<div id="container">

    <div id="left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
        <h3>Title goes in here</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but do you mean something like:

|pic| content |pic|?

try it with a few divs like:

```
<div class="image-left">
 <div class="image-right">
  <div class="content">
   <!-- rarndom content -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and in the css define the styles like (for example the pictures you want in the edges have a size of 50px width and height):

```
.image-left{
 background:url(/images/left-banner.png) no-repeat left;
 height:50px; 
 padding-left:50px;
 width:100%;
}
.image-right{
 background:url(/images/right-banner.png) no-repeat right;
 height:50px;
 padding-right:50px;
 width:100%;
}
.content{
 /* you can also define styles for padding or whatever you want */
 width:100%;
}
```

insert for height the height of your picture or of the banner and for the padding-left and padding-right values the width of your pictures you want. And of course set the right paths in the url ;) (i worked with a similar structure and it was working)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I tried adding some placeholder images to your code and found that the content div is overlapping image left. Also, image right disappears beyond the browser window to the right. This is probably something I've done without realising, but any help you can give me will be useful.

Comment: try it with margin-left:50px; for the content-div and mybe margin-left:-50px; for the image-right div ... I'm not sure if it's working but I remember I had something like this in my special case.

Comment: Still can't get it working correctly. Do you know if there's any tutorials for this? I can't seem to find one that covers exactly what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: could you show me a screenshot of the actual problem?

Comment: I don't have the privileges to add images yet as I'm a new user, but you can see an example on the following page http://umaar.github.io/css-flexbox-demo/ at the bottom where it says: Here's one more example where div:nth-child(2) (the 2nd item) is set to flex: 20;. You may suggest just using Flexbox, but its not yet supported on all browsers. Any further suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the same gradient background image the html will look like this:

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
        #banner{
            width:100%;
            height:400px;
            background: url('bg.gif') 0 0 repeat;
        }

        .text-content{
            width:960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            /* background-color:#ffffff; */
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="banner">
            <div class="text-content">
               Lorem ipsum
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am hoping to use a CSS gradient so I can scale the content without any pixelation. Will this affect the code above at all (other than swapping the bg.gif to a CSS gradient). Also, as the other users response suggests I want image | gradient | image